# Error 502 Bad Gateway al descargar repositorios de un GOPROXY Nexus privado para golang

Tags: go

Estamos realizando pruebas con un GOPROXY en Nexus de una empresa. Realizamos los pasos:

`go mod init`

`go mod tidy`

`go mod vendor`

`go mod download`

No tenemos problemas en el local, incluso revisando el repo Nexus vemos las librerías descargadas en el cache, pero al realizar el build para su liberación se presentan errores de BAD GATEWAY en la descarga de los archivos ZIP

> reading http://NEXUS:8081/repository/goproxy/github.com/basgys/goxml2json/@v/v1.1.0.zip: 502 Bad Gateway
> reading http://NEXUS:8081/repository/goproxy/github.com/golang/protobuf/@v/v1.3.3.zip: 502 Bad Gateway
> reading http://NEXUS:8081/repository/goproxy/golang.org/x/sys  /@v/v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42.zip: 502 Bad Gateway
> reading http://NEXUS:8081/repository/goproxy/gopkg.in/yaml.v2/@v/v2.2.8.zip: 502 Bad Gateway